# BackgroundMediaPlayer set Uri source of Media library item

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1

WP 8.1 have BackgroundMediaPlayer to play background audio.

http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player/

In this tutorial author setting up ms-appx source to play song:

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/Ring01.wma"));
```

Successful.
But, how can I SetUriSource up with Audio from Music Library? Using only SetUriSource because:

> The new background player got three simple methods for playing songs. SetFileSource, SetStreamSource and SetUriSource. Only one of these can be called from the foreground application, namely the SetUriSource method. The others needs to be used from your task instead. The reason for this is that the background player don´t have access to the memory where SetFIleSource or SetStreamSource is located unless it is set in the task.

Where I can read advanced about WP8.1? 
Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your Uri with a file from *MusicLibrary* by using file's full system path. For example like this:

```
StorageFile file = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. new Uri(pathSource, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) has this string:{file:///C:/Data/Users/Public/Music/CD - 1/Test001.mp3}

Comment: But new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/Ring01.wma") is working fine.

Comment: @RegisteredUser As I've tested it's working just fine. Can you try with: `new Uri(@"C:/Data/Users/Public/Music/CD - 1/Test001.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)`? Also have you added in capabilities MusicLibrary?

Comment: Not working... Music Capabilities is added. By the way, music from Assets/Media playing not fully. Just stopping after 3-4 seconds. Can you share your code with me?

Comment: My code for background task is: `public sealed class AudioPlayer : IBackgroundTask     {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstanceOnCanceled;
        }

        private void TaskInstanceOnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            _deferral.Complete();
        }
    }`

Comment: @RegisteredUser There are many pitfalls where your code can fail. Have you tried to debug your code - especially AudioPlayer - MediaOpened event? Maybe you can try to download [the official sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) and test on it?

Comment: I'm already working with official sample. When I add @"C:/Data/Users/Public/Music/Music/CD - 1/Test001.mp3" or "file:///C:/Data/Users/Public/Music/Music/CD - 1/Test001.mp3" to 'tracks' of String[] in MyPlaylistManager.cs, and run application, nothing. Player stopping playing after 'Assets/Media/Ring03.wma' source. Just in case, MusicLibrary cap is enabled.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Ok then in this sample, remove everything in rewind button, put the code from my answer in that event (make it async). Copy one mp3 file to your Phone/Music. Run in debug mode. Push play button, it should start playing ring... Then stop it. Click rewind button, (don't care about its accent color). Open SMTP (hit volume button on the phone), hit play there. Now it should play the first file found in Phone/Music.

Comment: Nothing... Can I share solution with you?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56619/discussion-between-romasz-and-registered-user).

Comment: I found one interesting thing. Then I call: `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetFileSource(file);`

It's playing! But if I use SetUriSource - nothing.
I'm calling SetFileSource directly from AudioPlayer Windows Runtime Component

Comment: @RegisteredUser Yes all methods setting the track work when run for AudioPlayer. Consider sending a message from foreground with for example string with a path to a file. Then when AudioPlayer receives the message you can set it to play.

Comment: Yes I did that, working perfect. But I don't know why SetUriSource not working...

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use SetUriSource to access files from the library or removable storage, at least not from the background task. You need to use SetFileSource or SetStreamSource instead. This is not documented anywhere, unfortunately.