# BackgroundMediaPlayer not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, background-music

I have set up a Windows Phone project along with its associated BackgroundTask project, and have also done the needed declarations as explained in [this article](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2014/05/02/windows-phone-81ndashbackground-audio-in-windows-phone-store-apps).

I need to select an audio file from the app UI (from the Music Library), and assign it to the BackgroundMediaPlayer to play it, so that the song can be played when the UI is in foreground, and also when it is suspended or the screen is locked.

I have tried the following but it does not work:

**Set file path from UI:**

```
StorageFile file = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(
"Song from Music Library.mp3"));
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new System.Uri(file.Path, 
UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
```

Result: No audio is played. No exceptions are thrown.

**Pass the file path as string to the backgroundtask, search for the file from Music Library and play it:**

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> songs = await 
KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
StorageFile fileToPlay = songs.AsQueryable().Single(
s => s.Path == toPlay);
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetFileSource(fileToPlay);
```

Result: The debugger does not move forward after "StorageFile fileToPlay = songs.AsQueryable().Single(s => s.Path == toPlay);". It just stops there.
Again, no audio is played. No exceptions are thrown.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Has your BackgroundPlayer started? Have you debuged it?

Comment: Yes.. I found the issue. The BackgroundMediaPlayer initialization was not happening.

It works now, however sometimes it throws this exception:
"Background Audio Task didn't start in expected time"

Is it due to some latency period required for the BackgroundMediaPlayer to start?

Comment: They can be many reasons why the task hadn't started - your code can be closed due to system policy or other. Watch out not to start two tasks simultanously.

Answer (score 0):

[BackgroundMediaPlayer set Uri source of Media library item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509852/backgroundmediaplayer-set-uri-source-of-media-library-item)

```
StorageFile file = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

See the answer.